# SQL Query logic to Django ORM Query logic

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have tried to think about how the following SQL query would be structured as a Django ORM query but I have had no luck in my multiple attempts. Can anyone help?

`SELECT targets_genetarget.gene, count(targets_targetprediction.gene) as total
FROM targets_genetarget
LEFT OUTER JOIN targets_targetprediction on targets_targetprediction.gene = 
      targets_genetarget.gene
WHERE list_name LIKE %s
GROUP BY targets_genetarget.gene`

```
class GeneTarget(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gene = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('list_name', 'gene'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name


class TargetPrediction(models.Model):
    specimen_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patient_peptide = models.ForeignKey(Peptide, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Peptide", related_name="predictions")
    allele = models.ForeignKey(Allele, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Allele", related_name="predictions")
    gene = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('specimen_id', 'patient_peptide', 'allele', 'gene'),)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/samples/specid-{self.specimen_id}'

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'Specimen: {self.specimen_id} Peptide: {self.patient_peptide} Allele: {self.allele} Gene: {self.gene} ')
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: Ok. I added my models!

Comment: gene is not explicitly a key at the moment but it can be used in a join

Comment: well Django does not have a (convenient) way to join on non-relations, except for raw queries, so this will make the query not (much) better than just the raw query you already have.

Comment: Yeah I am using django raw query right now because I could not figure out to turn this into an ORM query. Assuming that the gene column was a relation do you have any ideas as to how an ORM query would be structured? That is something I could think about changing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you declaring the `TargetPrediction.gene` field as a foreign key using the `to_field` attribute, so you wouldn't need to change the data at all:

```
class TargetPrediction(models.Model):
    ...
    gene = models.ForeignKey("GeneTarget",  to_field="gene")
```

Now your query simply becomes:

```
GeneTarget.objects.filter(list_name="whatever").values("gene").annotate(total=Count("targetprediction"))
```

Comment: Does this account for the left outer join in my query? (not an inner join)